# As of 2017, is there a more direct route for a car between Killarney and Manitoulin Island?

Tags: ontario

[image]

My grandparents plan to drive to Tobermory then Killarney Provincial Park. Is [the blue route](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Manitoulin+Island,+Ontario/Killarney,+ON/@45.9500248,-81.483353,8.29z/data=!4m13!4m12!1m5!1m1!1s0x4d323b9a7ed851e1:0xaeb4a12150af6342!2m2!1d-82.0371761!2d45.7026471!1m5!1m1!1s0x4d2e96f4ce287103:0xe7ba2c9a9e51272c!2m2!1d-81.5114972!2d45.9719137) truly the fastest (it wastes fuel and time because the SLD is evidently much shorter)? No vehicle ferry?

[This](http://forums.redflagdeals.com/shortcut-between-killarney-area-manitoulin-island-1083987/) asks the same question but is dated from 2011.

Comment: Manitoulin is not the kind of place where major new road construction is done very often.

Comment: I like "You can snowmobile across in no time in the winter". But seriously, with islands (or indeed anywhere with limited access routes) it's *always* going to be the case that there are places where the straight-line distance is much much less than the accessible-route distance. This area looks like it's been deliberately left undeveloped, to boot.

Comment: Actually Manitoulin Island is not short of roads. It is like a misplaced bit of southern Ontario, they have dead-straight square-grid lot and concession line roads every mile or so. Killarney, on the other hand, is a village (Google says 389 people now) bordering on an exceptionally rugged bit of northern Ontario (hence the park). No one is rushing to improve access to Killarney, one (long) highway is plenty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In google maps you can see the ferry routes as a dotted line in the water. In your map you can see that the only route by ferry is from Tobermory, and is really far...

I couldn´t find any other ferry that gogle does not know so I am sorry but I would say that there are no other available options, except for land travel.

One thing to try is to go to some harbour and look for a ship that can take a car, ask the owner if he would like to do this trip and for how much. Anyways you have to be so lucky for this and even that maybe it will take the same time or more as with car or be really expensive

Comment: Harbours round Manitoulin are not suitable for ships big enough to carry cars, with the obvious exception of South Baymouth, which doesn't help you.

Comment: So then no turn around, it must be by road only